# pandasで少し複雑なデータの選択を行いたい

Tags: python, pandas

Pandasでデータ処理をしています。以下のデータセット（df）で、 A列（IDです）の値が2の行ではE列の値が1のみ（0が存在しない）4の行ではE列の値が0のみ（1が存在しない）です。このようなデータから、E列の値が0と1の両方を含むデータだけを取り出したいです。（A列が2と4の行を削除して、A列が1、3、5の行だけを残したいです。）
何か良い操作があればご教示くださいませんか？

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
1   1   0   0   0   1   1163.7
2   1   0.8 0.8 2.2 0   0
3   1   0.2 0.2 4.4 0   0
4   1   0.8 0.4 0.4 0   0
5   1   0.5 0.7 3.8 0   0
6   2   1   1   8.9 1   116
7   2   1.5 1.5 1.7 1   116
8   2   2   2   8.7 1   116
9   3   3   3   5.  0   0
10  3   4.5 4.5 2.2 0   0
11  3   6.0 6.5 0.8 0   0
12  3   8   8   0.3 0   0
13  3   5.3 0   0   1   116
14  3   0   0   0   1   116
15  4   0.8 0.8 1.1 0   0
16  4   0.2 0.5 3.4 0   0
17  4   0.4 0.8 3.2 0   0
18  4   0.7 0.5 3.0 0   0
19  5   1   1   1.5 0   0
20  5   1.5 1.5 1.7 0   0
21  5   2   2   7.9 1   116
・
・
・
```

以下が目標とするデータセットです。

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
1   1   0   0   0   1   1163.7
2   1   0.8 0.8 2.2 0   0
3   1   0.2 0.2 4.4 0   0
4   1   0.8 0.4 0.4 0   0
5   1   0.5 0.7 3.8 0   0
6   3   3   3   2.2 0   0
7   3   4.5 4.5 2.2 0   0
8   3   6.0 6.5 0.8 0   0
9   3   8   8   0.3 0   0
10  3   5.3 0   0   1   116
11  3   0   0   0   1   116
12  5   1   1   1.5 0   0
13  5   1.5 1.5 1.7 0   0
14  5   2   2   7.9 1   116
・
・
・
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

元のデータが`df`に入っているとして、以下のように出来るでしょう。

```
droprows = []
grouped = df.groupby('A')
for i, dfw in grouped:
    if dfw['E'].value_counts().shape[0] < 2:
        droprows.extend(dfw.index)

df.drop(index=droprows, inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df.index += 1
```

ちなみに目標とするデータセットに元データの`9   3   3   3   5.  0   0`の行のデータが抜けていますが、それはコピーミスですよね？

Comment: 申し訳ございません。コピーミスです。訂正致しました。ありがとうございました。